# Logic App take first 5 characters from the items in array

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I would like to be able to extract the first 5 characters from the element in the array in Logic App. I am able to generate the list (below image) but I need only first 5 characters not the whole name

[image]

and here is the result

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Is that the result or the json you want to use as the source for the first 5 characters?

Comment: The result to be with first 5 characters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using substring function you can extract first five characters of the file name**. I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps I followed,

1. Created logic app as shown below,
   [image]
2. Taken http trigger and then initialized a variable of type array.
   [image]
3. Next listing Azure blobs in storage account.

[image]

4. In foreach loop, iterating over list of blobs and then appending display name of blob to array variable. Here using **substring function to take first 5 characters of file name** with expression,

**substring(items('For_each')?['DisplayName'],0,5)**

[image]

5. Creating blob with using content as array variable output.
6. File names in storage account displayed as shown below,
   [image]
7. Logic app ran successfully and blob created in storage account as shown below,
   [image]

[image]